# stream.show() without interrupting code in music21 (similar to matplotlib.pyploy.show(block=False))

Tags: python, image, music21

I am working on a custom interactive python shell that allows the display of images (scores, crucially) and I am using music21 to process the musicxml files. I want the user to be quickly able to display (part of) a score in PNG format and be able to compare different parts of scores. However, stream.show('musicxml.png') freezes the terminal until the image is closed which makes doing so clunky. Is there a way to not interrupt the code while showing a score in music21 (like how you can do pyplot.show(block=False) in matplotlib to achieve exactly this with displaying plots)?

Comment: Is this reproducible in v.6.5? We now use `subprocess.run` instead of `os.system` for these file launching operations, and I think that should avoid the interruptions you refer to.